# how session data is transferred via ajax request in Flask(Python)

Tags: ajax, flask, session

## Flask and Ajax request question

Please tell me, otherwise I don't understand, when I send an ajax request to my Flask server, when I try to output data from the session, it shows me my session?

An example of an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    headers: {
                        "Admin-ajax-id": userId
                    },
                    url: '/edit_product',
                    data: JSON.stringify(product_data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.status == 'success') {
                            $(button).closest('.footer-card').append('<div class="alert-custom">' + response.message + '</div>');

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                button.closest('.footer-card').find('.alert-custom').fadeOut(250, function () {
                                    $(this).remove();
                                });
                            }, 500);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And on the server side:

```
@app.route('/edit_product', methods=['POST'])
def edit_product():
    print(session)
    ...
```

It gives me:

<SecureCookieSession {'_fresh': True, '_id': 'c184b14b9bdcb44bd90e7ade2b14c36e604c86844d4e549822423830918940556914eb60cda2356f333ada2916de49dc90cebd4173c48ffb3d9149a6e5ec1f96', '_user_id': '10675480-72f7-483b-9226-362edcda1611', 'csrf_token': '939b066478e8bcbada195add831da7f3b7149590'}

How is that possible, thank you!

My question does not contain a problem, I just want to clarify how it works, because in open access I could not find an answer to this question, so I decided to ask here

Comment: The default out-of-the-box session is a cookie [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#sessions). They are not secure and can be inspected by your users, just not modified.